# Select distinct column value based on haversine distance formula?

Tags: php, mysqli, haversine

I am trying to query all distinct `category column values` based on the distance from the user. As of now it just outputs all of the column values based on the distance instead of the reverse. I'd like to somehow query `DISTINCT category WHERE distance < ?`
 but all I get an error saying its an unknown  column. Here is my attempt:

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT category,
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM tasks
WHERE status='o' 
HAVING distance < ?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_POST['lat'],$_POST['lng'],$_POST['lat'],$_POST['distance']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($category,$distance);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`
It acts like distinct

```
$sql="SELECT category,
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM tasks
WHERE status='o'
GROUP BY category 
HAVING distance < ?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_POST['lat'],$_POST['lng'],$_POST['lat'],$_POST['distance']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($category,$distance);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
}
```